# Get the data from the Partial View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view that is strongly typed. I have a drop down inside that partial view. I have rendered that partial view on the view. I need to get the item that was selected on the dropdown on the form submit. How do I get it?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give that drop down a name attribute at render time. Then, in post Controller Action, make sure to have a string with the same name as a parameter. Binding is done automagically for you by the framework

For example, in your view, you'd have something like this:

```
Html.DropDownList("myDropDown", SomeListOfValues);
```

Then in your controller's post action:

```
public ActionResult MyPostAction(string MyDropDown) {
   // do whatevs with it
}
```

P.S. same idea works even if you construct your list using just HTML. Set some breakpoints and try it out for yourself

Comment: I had made a mistake in the name(in the controller), found it thanks a ton.